# Can't storing data in database received from ajax call in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-4

```
Route::get('/comment/{data}', function($data){


        if (Request::ajax()) {

        //echo $data; *i checked here echo prints the content of $data but i cant store it in database. i dont know why its not store by using below code plz help me to find error.

        $comm = new Data;
        $comm->details = Input::get('data');
        $comm->save();

    }
});
```

Comment: I am new to laravel 4 plz help me to recover the mistakes in the above code. It returns the "500 Internal Server Error"

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::post('/comment/{data}', function($data){
}
```